# Add model parameters in facet plots, being the parameters printed in multiple lines with italic font but their indexes in plain font and in subscript

Tags: r, ggplot2, printing, facet

I wish to add some estimated model parameters in facet plots, being the parameters printed in multiple lines with italic font but their indexes in plain font and in subscript.
Bellow I provide a minimal example:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Some fake parameter estimates
b1 <- c("2.33", "1.29", "1.15")
b2 <- c("4.45", "2.32", "2.28")
b3 <- c("2.30", "1.23", "2.10")

labs <- paste0("b1 = ", b1,
"\nb2 = ", b2, "\nb3 = ", b3)

dat <- data.frame(
  x = rep(7, 3),
  y = rep(41, 3),
  drv = unique(mpg$drv),
  labels = labs)

p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
     geom_point() +
     geom_smooth(span = 0.8) +
     theme_bw() +
     facet_wrap(~drv) +
     geom_text(data=dat,
               aes(x,y,
               label=labels),
               hjust=1,    
               size = 3.6,
               inherit.aes=FALSE)
p
```

[image]

In this plot I needed that the estimated model parameters be printed like this:

[image]

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the code below, we use `plotmath` expressions for the italics and subscripts. I don't know of a way to include linebreaks in `plotmath` expressions, so I add each coefficient label separately using `lapply` to run `geom_text` three times. `parse=TRUE` inside `geom_text` ensures the `plotmath` expressions are interpreted properly. I doubt this is the most elegant approach, but it works.

```
# Some fake parameter estimates
b1 <- c("2.33", "1.29", "1.15")
b2 <- c("4.45", "2.32", "2.28")
b3 <- c("2.30", "1.23", "2.10")

# Set up data frame of text coordinates
dat <- data.frame(
  x = rep(5, 3),
  y = rep(41, 3),
  drv = unique(mpg$drv))

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(span = 0.8) +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~ drv) +
  # Add three lines of regression coefficients using lapply
  lapply(1:3, function(i) {
    dat = cbind(dat, lab=get(paste0("b",i)))          # Add coefficient values to dat
    dat$lab = paste0("italic(b)[",i,"] == ", dat$lab) # Add plotmath expression to get italics and subscript
    dat$y = dat$y - 1.6*(i - 1)                       # Set vertical position of each coefficient label
    geom_text(data=dat, aes(x, y, label=lab), hjust=0,    
              size = 3.6, parse=TRUE, inherit.aes=FALSE)
  })
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @eipi10, in the codes you provided I tried inserting the following code line before `geom_text()`: `dat$lab <- sapply(dat$lab,deparse)`, which allowed printing trailing zeros (present in **b3=2.30** and **b3=2.10**) but unfortunately it caused an issue when printing the `plotmath` expression.
Do you have any suggestion of how trailing zeros could also be printed? I’ve researched other "trailing zero" questions in Stackoverflow but none seems to apply to this type of situation. Thank you again for your codes, it really helped :)

Comment: Yes, these expression parsing issues often seem more complicated than they ought to be. I haven't come up with a solution for keeping the trailing zeros, but I will update my answer if I think of something.

Comment: Indeed @eipi10, expression parsing issues really seem more complicated than they ought to be. But anyway, thank you for your codes and the reply, it sure helped.